# Assigning scalar value to numpy array via indexing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, assign, assignment-operator

I am not able to assign a scalar value to a numpy array. I want to set all the values after 2nd row and 4th column in `x[0]` to be -10.0 leaving a block of 0s at the top-left corner of the matrix. It's like padding. None of the A, B, C, or D works for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
x= np.zeros((4, 10, 15,1), dtype=np.float32)
x[0][2:, 4:, :] = -10 # A
x[0][2:, 4:, :] = np.array(-10, dtype=np.float32) # B

x[0, 2:, 4:, :] = -10 # C
x[0, 2:, 4:, :] = np.array(-10, dtype=np.float32) # D

x[0][0].flatten() # array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=np.float32)
```

UPDATE:

This worked for me. This is actually padding the matrix.

```
 x[0, 2:] = -10
 x[0, :, 4:] = -10
```

Comment: What values are you trying to set to `-10`?

Comment: How are you checking if they work?

Comment: Just added more info. I want to pad the array with -10s.

Comment: I think `C` does work. You want to set all the values after the 2nd row to be `-10`, but you are only displaying the first row with `x[0][0].flatten()`.

Comment: I see. I want a 0-matrix of size 1 x 3 at the top-left corner. I thought the above slicing will work. I think I need to do that in two steps.